# Spring 3.2 form with 2 buttons -- request syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-3

I have the following Spring 3.2 form.  It has two buttons, and I want to perform a different action depending on which button is clicked.

```
<form:form action="approve" method="post">
    <%
        List<Bulletin> bulletins = (List<Bulletin>) request.getAttribute("bulletins");
        for (Bulletin bulletin : bulletins) {
            bulletin.setNote(bulletin.getNote().replace("\n\n", "\n "));
            String[] bulletinArray = bulletin.getNote().split("\n");
            out.println("<b>Name:</b> " + bulletin.getName() + "<br>");
            out.println("<b>Date:</b> " + bulletin.getDate() + "<br>");
            out.print("<b>Comment:</b> ");
            for (int i = 0; i < bulletinArray.length; i++) {
                if (i == bulletinArray.length - 1) {
                    out.println(bulletinArray[i]);
                } else {
                    out.println(bulletinArray[i] + "<br />");
                }
            }
            out.println("<br><br>");
        }
    %>
            <td><input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="deny" value="Deny" /></td>
            <br />
        </form:form>
```

I have the following methods in my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/approve", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "approve" })
public String approve(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String approve, Model model) {
    try {
        bulletinDAO.approveBulletin(id);
        model.addAttribute("approval", "Your bulletin has been approved.");

        List<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinDAO.getApprovedBulletins();
        model.addAttribute("bulletins", bulletins);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "FailurePage";
    }

    return "redirect:/waitingBulletins";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/approve", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "deny" })
public String deny(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String deny, Model model) {
    try {
        bulletinDAO.denyBulletin(id);
        model.addAttribute("approval", "Your bulletin has been denied.");

        List<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinDAO.getApprovedBulletins();
        model.addAttribute("bulletins", bulletins);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "FailurePage";
    }

    return "redirect:/waitingBulletins";
}
```

Whichever button I click on, I get an HTTP Status 400 error with the description "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."  As you can see, each method has a parameter of type int.  It seems to me the problem is that I haven't accounted for that method in the form in my JSP, but I'm not clear about how to do that.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Let's see the rest of the form, if there is any.

Comment: Where should the `@RequestParam` for the `id` come from?

Comment: Also, you can turn your logger level to DEBUG to get more information from Spring.

Comment: I have added the remainder of the form.  I don't know where the @RequestParam should come from.  I think that's the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know where the @RequestParam should come from. I think that's
>   the crux of the problem.

Yes, absolutely. The [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) javadoc states

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter.

It can't do that if you don't have an appropriate request parameter. In your case, it doesn't seem like you have a request parameter for

```
@RequestParam int id
```

where the name of the request parameter will be `id` since you have provided a `value` attribute to `@RequestParam`. You need to provide such a request parameter, possibly with an `<input>` element.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have added this line to my form, which solved the problem:
`<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="${bulletin.getId()}"></td>`

Comment: @Frank You're welcome. Note that `@RequestParam` has a `required` attribute which you can set to `false`.